# how to pass start parameter into my kubernetes pod service

Tags: kubernetes

If I start the service using docker,It should look like this:

```
docker run -e PARAMS="--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-service.example.com/xxl-job?Unicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password=<mysql-password>" -p 8180:8080 -v /tmp:/data/applogs --name xxl-job-admin  -d xuxueli/xxl-job-admin:2.0.2
```

now I am running it in kubernetes(v1.15.2) cluster,how to pass the parameter into pod's container? I am trying to pass parameter like this:

```
"name": "xxl-job-service",
        "image": "xuxueli/xxl-job-admin:2.0.2",
        "args": [
          "--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-service.ttt208.com/xxl-job?Unicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password=<mysql-password>"
        ],
```

but it seem do not work,it throw :

```
19:19:55.563 logback [xxl-job, admin JobFailMonitorHelper] ERROR c.x.j.a.c.t.JobFailMonitorHelper - >>>>>>>>>>> xxl-job, job fail monitor thread error:{}
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
### The error may exist in class path resource [mybatis-mapper/XxlJobLogMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.xxl.job.admin.dao.XxlJobLogDao.findFailJobLogIds
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:77)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:230)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:139)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.findFailJobLogIds(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxl.job.admin.core.thread.JobFailMonitorHelper$1.run(JobFailMonitorHelper.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

what should I do to run this service success? I am sure the database username and password correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dockers `-e` or `--env` sets an environment variable.

The equivalent in a Kubernetes [pod spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#podspec-v1-core) is the [containers `env` field](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#container-v1-core)

```
  env:
  - name: PARAMS
    value: ' --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-service.example.com/xxl-job?Unicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password=<mysql-password>'
```